# Using sentry with a custom error handler in Express

Tags: node.js, express, sentry

I have an Express server running for the backend of a website with Sentry (v5.15.5) successfully implemented. I'm now trying to improve the error handling on the backend, as at the moment if something goes wrong with the request, the request is not ended and the client sits there waiting for a response, which it never gets.
To tell the client if the request has failed I'm using the custom error handler in the documentation:

```
app.use(function onError(err, req, res, next) {
  // The error id is attached to `res.sentry` to be returned
  // and optionally displayed to the user for support.
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end(res.sentry + "\n");
});
```

However, when I use this on my server, only the custom error handler runs - **Sentry never creates an event for the error**, but if I just use another custom error function, they both get called fine, which makes me think this is a Sentry issue. Here's the relevant parts of the server code:

```
...
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');
...

const app = express()

Sentry.init({ dsn: process.env.SENTRY });

...

// Middlewares
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());

app.use(express.json())
app.use(helmet())
app.use(cors())
app.use(morgan('tiny'))

const controllers = require('./controllers')

const wrap = fn => (...args) => Promise
    .resolve(fn(...args))
    .catch(args[2])

// Routes
...
app.post('/test', authUser, wrap(controllers.testController))
...

app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
app.use(function onError(err, req, res, next) {
    res.statusCode = 500
    res.end(res.sentry + "\n")
  })

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`APP RUNNING ON PORT ${PORT}`))
```

The controllers on the server make database requests, etc. so they are async functions - that's why I use the `wrap` function to catch promise rejections and pass them to the error handler. If I unwrap the controller then Sentry works fine, but then the server never sends the error to the client.

I expect I'm probably going about this wrong as it should be pretty simple to do, but no matter what I do I cannot get Sentry + async controllers + custom error handler to work. Any help would be appreciated.

(This may be an Express issue, if so let me know and I'll take it over there)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Sentry's 'Filter out localhost' option (which was turned off but somehow got toggled on) doesn't actually filter out all local errors. When I removed the custom error handler and wrap function, the errors managed to get past the localhost filter. After I turned it back off all the errors came through on Sentry fine.